# Kendo MVC Wrapper - Custom Editor if grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to get a custom popup editor working in our Grid using MVC wrappers.

The MVC wrapper is

```
Html.Kendo().Grid(@Model.ReferralCommentsViewModel.ReferralComments)   
    .Name("gridComment")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.CommentValue).Title("Comment").Encoded(false).Width(450);
        columns.Bound(p => p.CreatedBy).Title("Created By").ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(CreatedBy) #").Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.CreatedDate).Title("Create Date").ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(CreatedDate, \"MM/dd/yyyy\") #").Width(70);
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit().Text(" "); }).Title("Edit").Width(20);
        columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy().Text(" "); }).Title("Delete").Width(20);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add new Comment"))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("popupEditorTemplate").Window(w=>w.Title("Add/Edit Comment")))
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .Sortable()
    .Selectable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:165px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .AutoSync(false)
        .Batch(true)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.CommentID))
        .Create(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Create", "Referral"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("EditingPopup_Read", "Referral"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Update", "Referral"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Destroy", "Referral"))

    )
```

The editor template is -

```
<script id="popupEditorTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <label for="Created Date">Created Date:</label><Input data-bind= "value: CreatedDate" readonly="true" />
    <label for="Created By">CreatedBy:</label><Input data-bind= "value:CreatedBy" readonly="true" />
    <label for="Created By">Comments:</label>
    <textarea data-role="editor"
                      data-bind="value: CommentValue"
                      style="width: 280px"></textarea>

 </script>
```

No matter what options I use, I cannot get the custom edit template to display in the popup. Only the default popup is displayed.  Is there something obvious missing?

Project - VS2012, MVC4

Comment: What is not working? You don't get the popup? Or you get the popup with some unexpected content? or the saving is not working?

Comment: Sorry for not finishing my question.  We cannot get the custom popup edit template to display.

Comment: I suggest to read the FAQ about this configuration option: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-create-a-custom-popup-editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TemplateName** should specify the name of the view which is a cshtml in the **EditorsTemplate** folders which MVC searches automatically.

It should not be the name of a html element which holds a Kendo template (like you did). More info about MVC EditorTemplates can be found [here.](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html)

Comment: For those who, like me, don't know where the EditorsTemplate folder is, it's at \Views\Shared\EditorTemplates .